# How can i turn an ordered 3D model into a woocommerce product with variations?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, 3d

i want to make an wp multi vendor website with woocommerce, where visitors use this plugin https://www.wp3dprinting.com/product/3d-print-demo/ to calculate the cost of 3D printing for their model and then order it.

After an order is made i want to have this product created in woocommerce with some variations in color and material, so i can then give the ability to the creator to resell it from my site.

I have contacted the creator of the plugin but he doesn't make custom development so im depending on you to help me out:)

So my questions is on how can a woocommerce product beign made after the order of the model!

I have consider remaking the 3D model as a product myself but i prefer an automatic procedure for that!

Thank you in advance,
Romanos

Answer (score 0):

you might look into 3D plugins for woocommerce such as Verge3D. The procedure is lengthy but rather straightforward:

1. upload models to Wordpress and setup a 3d product view
2. add product variations with WooCommerce standard means
3. finally make the 3D view configurable by listening to woocommerce events and updating the webgl part. Verge3d got a visual editor to establish such a link - [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgvPp.jpg).